# Arguments in OOP

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I'm trying to learn a bit of OOP by rewriting a big function into a class. Here is a representation of the most important stuff with relevance to the question

```
function my_function( $args = [] ) {

    $defaults = [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
        'key3' => 'value3'
    ];
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    return $q->posts;

}
```

The user can then use the function as follow

```
echo my_function( ['key2' => 'new value'] );
```

`key2` here is set with a new value which in turn will alter the output of `$q->posts`

Now, my question is, how to I make this work in OOP. I had a look at the setters and getters, but does not seem that this is what I'm looking for. I also had a look at how the `WP_Query` class does it in Wordpress, but frankly, the coding is quite crappy and very outdated and definitely not something to learn from.

With the `WP_Query` class in mind I should have a class like

```
class My_Class {}
```

and then I can use it as follow

```
$output = new My_Class( ['key2' => 'new value'] );
```

How do I set arguments in a OOP class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is you wrap WP_Query which does the work for you:

```
class MyClass {

    private $defaults = array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
        'key3' => 'value3'
    );
    private $wpQuery;

    public function __construct($args = array()) {
        $this->wpQuery = new WP_Query(wp_parse_args($args, $this->defaults));
    }

    public function getPosts() {
        return $this->wpQuery->posts;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working as I expect it to be as as I need it to be. :-)

Comment: Would have upvoted you again if you could upvote more than once :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need an object for that.
If your routine always needs to return `$q->posts` converting your function just to use the methods to pass the arguments it's not a good idea.

Comment: HA! See your point. Did not really take that into account. Still, it would be a nice to know though

Answer (score 1):

Your class **My_Class** should have a constructor like this :

```
 <?php
class My_Class {
    private $attr;
    function __construct($arg) {
        $this->attr = $arg;
    }
    public function getAttr() {
        return $this->attr;
    }
}
// test
$obj = new My_Class(array('key2' => 'new value'));
var_dump ($obj->getAttr());
```

But in PHP, only one constructor is allowed, there is no overload in constructor, functions and methods...

Comment: There is a parse error in your code. *syntax error, unexpected 'getAttr' (T_STRING)*

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to remember is that classes offer you an easy way to separate out logic into small chunks whilst maintaining functionality in a single wrapper (the created object) that share properties and methods (functions).

To answer your question, you make mention of getters and setters. These are two very useful patterns to use when coding up the class itself. They give you a programmatic way to get and retrieve values that in turn provide you with ways to validate when settings and mutate when getting.

```
class MyClass {

    /**
     * Declare a private class property.
     * This is useable in scope of THIS class
     * and none other, not even extensions of this class.
     * has default args populated
     **/
    private $myArgs = ["key" => "value"];

    /**
     * Constructor.
     **/
    public function __construct()
    {
        // No need for constructor to do anything if args are
        // are already assigned by default. Use the setter to
        // change them
    }

    /**
     * Get the arguments array
     **/
    public function getArgs()
    {
        return $this->myArgs;
    }

    /**
     * Set the arguments array
     * Typehint as an array to make sure myArgs will always
     * be an array and nothing else.
     **/
    public function setArgs(array $args)
    {
        $this->myArgs = $args;
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();

// Get the args
$args = $myClass->getArgs();

// Set the args to a new value
$myClass->setArgs(["key2" => "value2"]);

// Get the new args
$args2 = $myClass->getArgs();
```

Comment: Your code work almost. My question is, how can I set the default arguments inside the class and then override them with the user specified arguments. Or am I better of leaving my function as is?

Comment: Will test this over the weekend, thanks. Will be really busy as from today :-)